# Get only latest records from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that holds multiple records of a particular user with datetime, my requirement is that I need only latest record through query. I don't know how to get this type of data.

**Table**

```
Create Table tblReport(
USERID LONG, ReportDateTime Datetime
)
```

**Current Records**

```
USERID          ReportDateTime 
1               2017-04-18 21:41:33.903
4               2017-04-20 01:16:00.653
4               2017-04-26 20:00:20.497
71              2017-04-17 22:31:37.437
4               2017-04-26 20:01:20.933 
225             2017-04-20 00:58:10.253
225             2017-04-25 23:09:34.433
1               2017-04-18 23:35:00.567
```

**Desired Output**

```
USERID          ReportDateTime 
1               2017-04-18 23:35:00.567
4               2017-04-26 20:01:20.933
71              2017-04-17 22:31:37.437 
225             2017-04-25 23:09:34.433
```

**My Query**

```
select USERID,max(ReportDateTime) from tblReport group by USERID, ReportDateTime order by USERID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `ReportDateTime` from your `group by`.

```
select 
    UserId
  , ReportDateTime = max(ReportDateTime)
from tblReport
group by userid
order by userid
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CLQ69624

returns:

```
+--------+-------------------------+
| UserId |     ReportDateTime      |
+--------+-------------------------+
|      1 | 2017-04-18 23:35:00.567 |
|      4 | 2017-04-26 20:01:20.933 |
|     71 | 2017-04-17 22:31:37.437 |
|    225 | 2017-04-25 23:09:34.433 |
+--------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Better to use the more standard "MAX(ReportDateTime) AS [ReportDateTime]" syntax. But otherwise, yes, exactly this.

Comment: @pmbAustin Define better? They perform the same. One is ANSI standard true, but I don't know if that makes it "better". [Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)

Comment: that's awsome, how i was miss?

Comment: Better in that it's more readable, makes more sense, is more standard, and is less confusing... "=" looks like assignment, like math... and in this case it's neither. There is no way I would accept anyone claiming it's a "bad habit' to do the RIGHT thing and use the "AS" keyword consistently to introduce an alias for a column. It's a BAD habit to use "=". Just like it's a bad habit to use string literals for column names and aliases. The article links to a contrived example, imho... in most cases I've seen it, the "=" syntax is a lot LESS readable. You can abuse anything, after-all.

Comment: How can be something be more or less standard? It either is or it is not the standard. I prefer using = because I can put the column names on the left side where they are easy to spot and the sometime long calculations and such can be lost over there on the right side only to be visited again if I need to look at how they were calculated. Neither is actually correct or incorrect. And following the well written article from Aaron I also prefer #2 because for me it is a lot easier to read.

Comment: @pmbAustin I'm not saying your _opinion_ is wrong, I'm just trying to point out that it is your opinion, which I wouldn't say is better than my opinion. I simply disagree with your evaluation of which is more readable. As there is no performance impact either way I would prefer to write code that I find easier to read, as I would expect you to write code you find easier to read.

Comment: @pmbAustin More readable?  As developers, we deal with objects and abstracts.  The object in this case is ReportDateTime, not how we got there.  I find it exausting to have to read through code just to find this is not the line that I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, more readable. When you're not comparing "the very best possible formatting of A" against "the worst possible formatting of B" to bias the results, then yes, it's more readable. Consistently. "=" means assignment or quality (as in a JOIN's ON clause). AS is always, consistently, introducing an alias. As long as you're consistent, and not writing spaghetti code to begin with, it's definitely more readable. I always reformat to use AS whenever I see "=" and will continue to do so. It's the standard in our shop. AND ANSI standard.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the With Ties clause

```
Select Top 1 With Ties *
 From tblReport 
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By UserID Order by ReportDateTime Desc)
```

Comment: @Anjyr Then tha't a good thing.  I learn something new every day on this site.  That is why I'm a HUGE fan.